# How to have specific routing in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to know how to have specific adrressing in MVC.net 4 
I have 3 url types in my web application
1-www,site.com/rss.xml 
2-www.site.com/amir (this type of addresses are reserved for my users and i want to put my site's usernames in order to create a profile address for each of my users)
3-www.site.com/article/detail/1

And my RouteConfig file is like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "RSS_route", // Route name
          url: "rss.xml", // URL with parameters
          defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "RSS", area = "" } // Parameter defaults
           , namespaces: new[] { "Clinic.WebUI.Controllers" }
     );

 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Doctor",
     url: "{docname}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Doctor", action = "Doctor", docname = "test" }
  , namespaces: new[] { "Clinic.WebUI.Controllers" }
 );

 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    , namespaces: new[] { "Clinic.WebUI.Controllers" }
 );

 routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Article",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{subject}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, subject = UrlParameter.Optional }
      , namespaces: new[] { "Clinic.WebUI.Controllers" }
   );
```

but the problem is that all these 3 url types are not accessible, and only the 2nd works
i would be happy if anyone can help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Have you even looked at MSDN as they have a perfectly reasonable answer that make sense here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_2

All i did to get that result was google "ASP.net MVC 4 routing" and it was the 3rd result...

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: thanks in advace for all your effort, but i think you just read the title, all in all i've read all your refrence but still my problem is remain 
as i've mentioned above i want to have all those 3 urls type be match.

Comment: My point was to not edit the RouteConfig and insted do it in the application code and see if that works?